# Saving belongs-to associations in Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm brand new to Phoenix/Elixir and am having some trouble saving a model with a belongs_to association.

The setup is that I have a User model that belongs_to a JobTitle model. In the database the user has a job_title_id field. I am updating the user using a JSONAPI input, and trying to change the job_title_id from 1 to 2. The user does update correctly, except for the job_title_id which does not. I have checked that my attrs variable in the controller does contain the correct value for job_title_id, but it is not being persisted to the database. Am I missing something obvious here? I'm using the JAserializer plugin.

Many thanks

```
defmodule PhoenixSandbox.User do
  use PhoenixSandbox.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :job_title, PhoenixSandbox.JobTitle
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name email bio)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Controller code:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "data" => data}) do
  user = Repo.get!(User, id)
  |> Repo.preload(:job_title)
  attrs = JaSerializer.Params.to_attributes(data)
  changeset = User.changeset(user, attrs)
  case Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(201)
      |> render(:show, data: user)
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(422)
      |> render(:errors, data: changeset)
  end
end
```

Details of the attrs variable in the controller:

```
%{"job_title_id" => "3", "name" => "Test 1", "type" => "user"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `job_title_id` to the list of optional (or required) params, and add [foreign_key_constraint/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3) to the pipeline in User#changeset